# ngFor - Can't bind to 'testid' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. how to concat id with string?

Tags: angular, angular8, angular-template-variable, angular-testing-library

I am trying to add the `index` value with my ids. but getting an error as:

```
Can't bind to 'testid' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.
```

here is my template:

```
<td *ngFor="let col of columns; let i = index"  [ngClass]="col.class" data-testid="form-create-td-{{i}}">
```

what is wrong with my code? any one help me?

Comment: what is testid?

Comment: adding for test requirement for get the id. if I remove `{{i}}` - works fine

Comment: Can you please share how you define the testid and how you calling it?

Comment: https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-queries#overriding-data-testid, please visit here. I use the testing-library

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think you will need property binding. So please try to replace below testid data property.

```
<td ... [attr.data-testid]="'form-create-td-' + i">
```

For concatenation id property with string, you are doing right thing.